# One finger lift up event for UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, gesture

I'm having problem with `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`. Is there a way (variable / method) to detect one finger lift-up event in its handler? I mean, I first put two fingers on the screen and enter pinch gesture began / changed state. Then, one finger keeps still on the screen and the other finger lifts up.

I have noticed that a gesture changed state may be fired when one finger lifts up, but the numberOfToucher is still 2. Is there any other variables / methods to get more information about the event?

I have tried to subclass `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and add `touchesEnded` to detect the finger lift-up event. It works, but the last 'gesture changed state' (see above) is fired right AFTER touchesEnded. Therefore, the only solution seems to set a flag in touchesEnded, and check that flag in the first following call in gesture handler, which I think is a poor solution.

Any better solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check property **numberOfTouches**. It changed after finger move, no right finger up. Checked in iOS9.

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer * gr = [ [ UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc ] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchAction:) ];
[ self.view addGestureRecognizer:gr ];

- (void)pinchAction:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gr
{
    if (gr.numberOfTouches < 2)
    {
        //
    }
}
```